# The Rock texture effect cannot be rendered!

Tags: rendering, texturing, modifiers, displacement

I got a render problem that the texture effect of my model could not be read. I tried to apply all modification but the result still not work when render. Please help! Thanks!!

[image]

Comment: Could it have anything to do with the object (figure) hidden in your viewport? Hidden objects are still visible in renders - perhaps it is "on top" of your (textured) model?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.